# WordPress .htaccess how to remove get parametrs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need to redirect form

```
http://example.com/category/news/?layout=grid&nav=load_more
```

to

```
http://example.com/category/news/
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match the query string portion of the URL you need to use mod_rewrite and use a condition to match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example, the following removes the query string from the example URL stated:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^layout=grid&nav=load_more$
RewriteRule ^category/news/$ /$0 [QSD,R,L]
```

This must go at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing WordPress directives.

`$0` is a *backreference* to the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (saves retyping the URL-path).

The `QSD` (Apache 2.4+) flag is required to discard the query string. However, if you are still on Apache 2.2 then you will need to append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* instead:

```
RewriteRule ^category/news/$ /$0? [R,L]
```

Comment: By "not working", you mean _nothing happens_ or some error or incorrect redirect? Please post your entire `.htaccess` file in your question, with this directive in place.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
Redirect /category/news/?layout=grid&nav=load_more http://example.com/category/news/
```

Comment: You can't match the query string with a mod_alias `Redirect` directive. (Note also, the OP is using WordPress.)